# Outlook 2013: Move any message without a To or Cc

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

How can I create an Outlook 2013 rule which moves any message that doesn't have me listed as a recipient? It's easy to do this for messages which aren't To me, but I only want it to trigger if I'm not on the To or the Cc.

**UPDATE:** These messages will still arrive, either through BCC, or, more commonly, through certain bulk mailers and mailing lists, which deliver mail without the To: header.

Comment: If your email address is not in the To, CC or BCC fields, how did you receive the messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a rule for all incoming messages (do not check any conditions) and set "**except if my name is in the To or CC box**" on the exceptions step.

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer: you aren't receiving those messages anyways... so you can't move them. You have to be in the email recepients to receive the emails